# Application of Identity Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let {$a_n$} and {$b_n$} be sequences of complex numbers such that each $a_n$ is non zero,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$$ and such that for every natural number k, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_{n}^k}=0$$
Suppose f is an analytic function on a connected open subset U of $\mathbb C$ which contains $0$ and all the $a_n$. Show that if $f(a_n)=b_n$ for every natural number n, then $b_n = 0$ for every natural number n.

I surmise that we have to apply the Identity Theorem of Complex Analysis and conclude that f is identically zero. This in turn will confirm that all $b_n$ are zero. But I am not able to choose the correct function for applying the Identity Theorem. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0 \in U$, $f$ has a power series expansion about the point $0$. So $f(z) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\alpha_iz^i$. We are done if we show that $\alpha_k = 0$ for each $k$. Now by hypothesis for each $n$

\begin{equation}
f(a_n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\alpha_ia_n^i = b_n
\end{equation}

divide this on both sides by $a_n^k$, we get

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha_ia_n^i}{a_n^k} = \frac{b_n}{a_n^k}
\end{equation}

For $k=0$, we get that $\alpha_0 = 0$. Now use induction and by taking limits as $n \to \infty$, show that $\alpha_k = 0$ for each $k$.

Comment: Identity Theorem is not used here as I thought. Taylor’s series is used for solving the problem. Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm glad to help, let me know if any further clarifications are required.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a non-zero analytic function, there exists an equivalent of $f(z)$ when $z$ tends to $0$ : $f(z) \simeq \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} z^k$, where $k$ is the smallest integer $l$ such that $f^{(l)}(0) \neq 0$.

Now, the limit tells us $b_n << (a_n)^k$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

However, we also know that $b_n = f(a_n) \simeq  \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}(a_n)^k $. This is absurd, so $f\equiv 0$ by connectedness of $U$.

Comment: Polynomials, sin z etc

Comment: Now apply this equivalent to $f(a_n)$.

Comment: I am sorry I don’t understand. There’s a limit involving $a_n$ and $b_n$. How should I use that??

Comment: @LawrenceMano I edited my answer.